# Why do I have to make my own drivers?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers

Why does *NIX require me to `make` (i.e. build) my own drivers to install them?

Couldn't they just be pre-built by the author and so long as they target the right CPU architecture I could install the binaries which would save me having to have all the right dependencies to build them.

I ask because I am currently faced with this problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154188/make-asus-pce-n15-driver-errors-on-steamos.

It has been suggested to me in another forum the the issue maybe they target an old version of the kernel - so what am I suppose to do in this instance? Are you telling me drivers target specific versions of the kernel and are tied to it - that sounds like a nightmare!

Comment: \*NIX _doesn't_ require you to compile your own drivers. In Linux distribution in which packages aren't compiled from source (most prominently Ubuntu), you download precompiled drivers and programs using the package manager.

Comment: OK, in my case I am using SteamOS which is based on Debian and using apt-get as it's package manger - though I have never installed drivers using apt-get, could you point me somewhere I can learn more? Thanks.

Comment: You install drivers using apt-get the same way you'd install any other program. You just need to figure out the package name that corresponds to the driver you need, and make sure it's in one of your repositories. If there isn't a package available that contains the driver, _then_ you probably need to compile it from the source code, but that's no different from how things work on any other OS.

Comment: I would say it is different, on Windows I go to the manufactures website download the driver and install it - I don't have to 'make' it. So the driver doesn't have to go through another party to get to me and I don't have to have the dependencies to build it.

Comment: fair point - I should say, if there isn't a package available that contains the driver, then you have to download it manually. If the manufacturer, or whoever provides the driver, has a prebuilt binary package, you use that; if they provide the source code, then you need to compile it. That much is OS-independent. However it's conventional to provide only binary packages for Windows and Mac, whereas it's more conventional to provide source code for Linux, probably due to the wide variety of configurations Linux systems can have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't necessarily a *NIX thing and is more of a Linux thing, IMO, and what you're considering as a annoyance is actually a good thing! That the drivers are made available in source form, rather than only in binary form.

There are many reasons why you want drivers to be avail. like this. Different architectures + kernel versions being 2 of them.

I completely understand your frustration but this is how Open Source generally works. I would pursue any building of drivers with the original authors or the distro that you're trying to build them on.

Answer (score 3):

> on Windows I go to the manufactures website download the driver and install it

Correct, and *those exact same manufacturers have the option of providing linux drivers.*  While it does require some effort to maintain them in relation to kernel versions, in most cases this maintenance effort would not be all that significant for the manufacturer.

**But they don't.** Why is somewhat conjecture, but: [This statistical survey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems#Desktop_and_laptop_computers) regarding desktop systems (using net applications) puts the linux "market share" at < 2%.  That sounds like it should be enough to make it worthwhile, but there are some things to consider in context:

- While gaming has provided a historical impetus the evolution of consumer hardware, *most* of the desktop market is still not gamers.  This is significant because games make specific demands of hardware -- but while desktop users whose focus is not gaming may (or may not) have special needs, they are not the same needs.
- Desktop users who are gamers and are frustrated by this situation will *mostly* be willing to fall back on MS Windows.

If you add these two factors together, the significance of that 2% market share becomes crippled.  Most of that 2% aren't gamers, and most of the ones that are will be perfectly willing to use Windows for their gaming needs.  **This means that the real $$ loss to manufacturers from consumers who won't buy their product because they don't provide linux drivers is negligible.**

Hence, they don't bother.  Would it cost them much? No. But would they have much to gain from it? No.  If the manufacturer won't bother, then it is mostly left up to volunteers to do the work.   Now consider, you are a software developer with some free time...

- If you like games and want to contribute, you almost certainly won't be starting with linux as a platform, because it isn't oriented that way.
- If you aren't interested in games, you are unlikely to want to spend time developing drivers that the actual equipment manufacturers didn't even want to bother with.  You want to contribute to things that you find interesting and useful -- which linux may be very suitable for, but that's not much help to end consumers of video games.

To draw a really crass analogy, complaining that a sailboat is more awkward than a pickup truck begs the question, *for what?*  People who build sailboats aren't trying to create pickup trucks.

Comment: Another reason - particularly where gaming and graphics drivers are concerned - is manufacturers tend to believe it *will* cost them a great deal. Nvidia, for instance, is infamously hesitant to open-source their drivers - specifically the video BIOSs - due to trade-secrets. They do provide closed-source drivers, of course, but it might not be too ridiculous to guess that a lot of the dev-work put into them is geared toward preventing reverse engineering. So sad...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, ironically I am a game developer porting our game to SteamOS so watch out - we are gonna put some wheels on that sailboat! :D